# How to make this Twisted Strokes Effect

Tags: adobe-illustrator, path, stroke

Does anybody recognise the below effect? I have tried to recreate this image in illustrator by putting a dark green circle with a dashed stroke on it and then apply Effect/Distort & Transform/Twist to that path, but that doesn't get me what I need.
Other things I tried are to make a dark green cross and apply Twist to that, but that doesn't work either. As I am not really an expert in Illustrator, I was wondering if someone recognises how the below is done and if you can point me in the right direction?

[image]

Answer (score -1, accepted):

This one you can make it without any effect:
[image: Vector view]

[image: Line View]

The stroke:
weight: 12px
Profile: Width Profile 4

To refine outsite-borders create a clipping mask.

I hope this works for you.

Peace!

Comment: Hi ricardo, welcome to GD.SE. Sorry, but I fail to see how this answers the question. After your minimal instructions, I still have no idea how to make the effect. Could you please clarify? Please don't be discouraged, we know that using this site can be a learning curve. We *are* happy to have you! Please check the [help center](http://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/help) if you have any questions

Comment: Hi Ricardo, Like Vincent said in his comment: could you please be a little more specific? I think you left out something in your answer to my question as I am not sure how you go from the square to the twisted lines...

Comment: Nevermind, I figured it out: I needed to create the curved lines by hand using the stroke settings provided by Ricardo. I then copied and rotated all of them in place. The square in his image had me confused. Thanks.